# Make Child element appear outside of parent

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slider on my page that has a height of 200px and has overflow hidden applied, inside this slider there are list items/images which are aall also 200px. When you hover over the image id like to show a tooltip above, my only problem is that the tooltip is hidden due to the overflow rule.

I thought id be able to show the tooltip by giving it a higher z index but that didnt seem to work, can you get child elements to break from their parent?

I hope this makes sense.

In brief my code structure is similar to the below

```
<div class="clip">
    <a href="" class="tooltip"><img src="myimage.jpg" style="height:200px;" /><span>tooltip stuff</span></a>
    <a href="" class="tooltip"><img src="myimage.jpg" style="height:200px;" /><span>tooltip stuff</span></a>
    <a href="" class="tooltip"><img src="myimage.jpg" style="height:200px;" /><span>tooltip stuff</span></a>
</div>
```

css...

```
.clip {
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:400px;
}

.tooltip {
    font-weight:bold;
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip a {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.tooltip span {
    margin-left: -999em;
    position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
    background: url("../images/backgrounds/black_arrow_big.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 163px;
    left: -100px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 40px 30px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    width: 310px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you can not get a child element to break the rules of a parent as you have described. Instead, you may want to attach the tooltip to a top level element such as document.body, and position it against the absolute position of your image with a little javascript

```
<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            position: relative;
        }
        #tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            display:none;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            z-index: 99;
            background-color: gold;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        .clip {
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #C0C0C0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        img {
            height: 200px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: #222222;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script>
    function imgover(img, tip) {
        document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('tooltip').innerHTML = tip;
        document.getElementById('tooltip').style.left = img.offsetLeft + 'px';
    }

    function imgout() {
        document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="tooltip">Tooltip Text</div>
    <div class="clip">
        <img onmouseover="imgover(this, 'Tip 1')" onmouseout="imgout()"/>
        <img onmouseover="imgover(this, 'Tip 2')" onmouseout="imgout()"/>
        <img onmouseover="imgover(this, 'Tip 3')" onmouseout="imgout()"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the trick by setting the position to `fixed` on your tooltip.
You'll have to set its position based on its parent by using negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `position: relative` to a container, it makes any children that have `position: absolute` be positioned absolutely *inside the container*. So (0,0) will be the top left corner of the container, not of the window. You can remove the `position: relative` from the container, but then you will have to know the exact x,y position to place the tooltip.

If you are using a fluid layout, you won't know where to position it. So instead, you can leave it with relative positioning, and then adjust it a little with JavaScript. Something like this:

```
var tooltips = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
    tooltips[i].style.top = tooltips[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.top - 200;
    tooltips[i].style.marginLeft = 0; // or display = "block" or whatever to show it
}
```

Note that this code is untested. Note also that getElementsByClassName is not supported in older browsers, but you can find a manual implementation of it if you search the web.