# use id attribute as reference or variable for tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I am currently using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363088/make-child-element-appear-outside-of-parent) .

However the text I wish to display must be in one line, and if there is a apostrophe ( ' ) in the text, it will not work anymore  .

```
 imgover(this, 'Text to display')
```

Is there a way to remplace the second variable of onmouseover by an id of a div so that it will display everything in the div please ?

Here is an example of the div :

```
<div id ="text1" >
    <em><img class="floatLeft" src="images/F9979.jpg" alt="" />
                                        TITRE DU FILM : Man of Steel
                <br />
                <br />
                  RESUME :
                   Film fantastique américain réalisé par Zack Snyder avec Henry Cavill, Amy Adams, Diane Lane
                <br />
                 <br />
                 DUREE : 2H23
                <br />
                Un petit garçon découvre qu'il possède des pouvoirs surnaturels et qu'il n'est pas né sur la Terre. Plus tard, il s'engage dans un périple afin de comprendre d'où il vient et pourquoi il a été envoyé sur notre planète. Mais il devra devenir un héros s'il veut sauver le monde de la destruction totale et incarner l'espoir pour toute l'humanité...

      </em>
</div>
```

I would like to remplace 'Text to display' from

```
 imgover(this, 'Text to display')
```

by what's in the div (text1) so that at the place where there is the div ( tooltip) I will see the text and the image from the div ( text1).

Comment: The more I read your question, the more confused I get. For instance, how will a text with an apostrophe not work? Why are you emphasizing everything in the div? And shouldn't "RESUME" be written "RÉSUMÉ"?

Comment: For exemple if I replace `'Text to display'` by `'J'ai réussi'`, it will display nothing, I thought it would display at least `J` but no. I put everything in the div because it is more easier to write the text in there. As for the french syntaxe I think in uppercase it is not considered as an error.

Comment: Well, the imgover function uses innerHTML to put the tip in the text, so you can use character references. But the rest of your question suggests that you don't even need that! As you already have the text you want to display inside the div, you can do away with the `tip` in the imgover function, and the text in the imgover call.

Comment: I suppose you mean to use innerHTML the same way as @MKorsch suggested, it works thanks.

Comment: No, I meant that because it uses innerHTML, you can replace apostrophes by their character references in the text. That is, write `'J&#39;ai réussi'` instead of `'J'ai réussi'`. That would have worked.

Comment: I see, but it would take too much time to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure whether I understood your question properly but this should work. You need to put the value of the `id` tag of your html element in the parameter of `getElementById`

```
<script>
    function imgover(img, tip) {
        document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML = tip;
        document.getElementById('text1').style.left = img.offsetLeft + 'px';
    }

    function imgout() {
        document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly I can't change getElementById('tooltip') since this is the place where the text will be displayed.  I updated the post to give more explanation.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Try: `imgover(this, document.getElementById('tooltip').innerHTML)`

Comment: I suppose you wanted to say `imgover(this, document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML`, but thanks it works ^^ .

Comment: Actually I wanted to say: Okay. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Try: `imgover(this, document.getElementById('text1').HTML())` But StackOverflow did not let me edit my Comment that frequently.. But now that it works everything's good!

Comment: If you do it like this, you will be replacing the content of the `text1` element by the very same content of the `text1` element. But hey, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: In the script balise I kept tooltip so that it will replace its content.